# Fortran 90 Resources?

Tags: resources, programming-languages, fortran

I'm taking Fortran 90 class, and I'm looking for any good websites about Fortran.

Does anyone know any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, comp.lang.fortran is pretty friendly group of people.

But, apart from that, what exactly are you looking for ? Some kind of introductory tutorial, something specialized ... you'll have to give more data.

Comment: I will check that.
I'm particularly looking for OPEN file and subprogram tutorial or any kinds of help.

Comment: Well, for statements and syntax in general, the best thing to go with is your compilers manual and "fortran",version,"handbook" series. Search a little, I think draft versions can be found downloadable on the net.

Comment: Apart from that, for general tutoring there are various books. I remember recommending Ramsden and Lin's to some of my friends - they seemed to be happy with it. Gortok also gave a few nice links, but for questions I still recommend c.l.f. -

Comment: people there are very friendly towards learners (just don't ask them to do your homework for you). If you really can't dig anything on the net, mail me, and I'll see what I have stacked up on the digital attic :-)

Comment: Hmm, google the above authors and check the first link :)

Answer (score 4):

- [Dmoz.Org Fortran 90/95 Tutorials](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Fortran/FAQs,_Help,_and_Tutorials/Fortran_90_and_95/)
- [Fortran.com Fortran 90 free online Tutorials](http://www.fortran.com/tutorials.html)
- [Free Programming Resources - Fortran](http://www.freeprogrammingresources.com/fortrantutr.html)
- [Tech Tutorials - Fortran](http://www.techtutorials.info/fortran.html)
- [Computer Science Department - Michigan Techological University](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/fortran.html)

Answer (score 0):

Gortok provided a good list - I'd add one more:

- [List of Fortran 90 intrinsic functions](http://www.nsc.liu.se/~boein/f77to90/a5.html)

Comment: I will check these websites. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, your first link is broken.

Comment: @astay13 - thanks!  I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 0):

Several Fortran 90 Online Courses:
http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/nmm1/Fortran/

Michael Metcalf's Fortran 90 article:
http://www.fortran.com/metcalf.htm

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a solid Fortran reference and was disappointed by all the previous links. I wanted more than a mere tutorial or list of intrinsics. What I ended up using are the actual standards documents, which are conveniently on the GNU GCC website: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranStandards

Answer (score 0):

Fortran 95 language features: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features